# Bubble sort on double linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort

Been at this for a few hours trying to get an implementation of bubble sort to work on a double linked list.  My code seems to work for one pass but then finishes prematurely without completing the sort.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void bubbleSort()
{
    Node cur = head.getNext();
    boolean done = false;

    while (!done)
    {
        done = true;
        while(cur != tail)
        {
            if (cur.getNext().getCount()>cur.getCount())
            {
                swap(cur.getNext(),cur);
                done=false;
            }
            cur = cur.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

The swap method I'm using appears to be corrupting the placement of the nodes until it's a circular loop between two nodes.

```
private void swap(Node n1, Node n2)
{
    Node b1, b2, a1, a2;
    System.out.println("Swapping n1: " + n1 + " with n2: " + n2);
    b1 = n2.getPrev();
    if (b1 == n1) // handle adjacent nodes
        b1 = n2;
    a1 = n2.getNext();

    b2 = n1.getPrev();
    if (b2 == n2) // handle adjacent nodes
        b2 = n1;
    a2 = n1.getNext();

    // swap

    n1.setPrev(b1);
    n1.setNext(a1);

    n2.setPrev(b2);
    n2.setNext(a2);

    b1.setNext(n1);
    a1.setPrev(n1);

    b2.setNext(n2);
    a2.setPrev(n2);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why not write a comparator http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html

Comment: In a linked list, swapping an element with its immediate successor is a special case. Was that case tested? You do need to go back to the start of the list for each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Run the code step by step for a simple list, and observe it's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems I see in your code:

- You should start from the `head`, not from `head.getNext()`.
- You should restart `Node cur` on every `while(!done)` iteration.

With these changes, your code should be

```
public void bubbleSort() {
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        Node cur = head;
        done = true;
        while(cur != tail) {
            if (cur.getNext().getCount()>cur.getCount()) {
                swap(cur.getNext(),cur);
                done=false;
            }
            cur = cur.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes your `swap` method works with no problems. Tested using `int count` as the data in your `Node` class assigning 10000 int values on the list.

---

EDIT: Based on your question edit, I made my `Node` class and `swap` function like this:

```
private static class Node {
    int count;
    Node next;
    //getters and setters...
}

//this function just swaps data, no need to swap the nodes prev and next
//(note that yours is an algorithm design issue)
private void swap(Node node1, Node node2) {
    int aux = node1.getCount();
    node1.setCount(node2.getCount());
    node2.setCount(aux);
}
```

No need to do all the boilerplate code that you have done in your `swap` implementation.

Comment: Then I get a null pointer error as the head and tail are sentinel markers.  It's the swap method I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @efnx I guess you have a problem in your LinkedList implementation though =\. I made a quick test and worked like a charm.

Comment: @efnx based on your question edit, why do you have all that boilerplate code? You only need to swap **the data in the nodes**!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `cur = head.getNext();` at the beginning of the outer loop works fine for my implementation of the linked list. So the problem is from the `swap` method or the implementation of your list.

According to your `bubbleSort` method, the `swap` method only swaps data of the nodes, not the nodes themselves. I mean, it just exchanges the value of `count`. If it is not the case, `swap` method is the problem. Otherwise, your implementation of double linked list has problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It's definitely the swap method.  Now I just need to figure out what's wrong.  For a simple n < 100 list it works fine, but for the n=1000 list I'm testing I have the failure.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to keep `cur = head.getNext();` at the end of the outer while loop, otherwise on the second pass the inner while loop will be skipped entirely and done will be true.

Have you considered the runtime of your bubble sort?  I noticed in your answer to MD.Unicorn that it worked fine for a list <100 but not for a list of 1000.  The list of 1000's expected runtime is at least 100 times slower than the list that is less than 100.  You may not be giving it enough time to finish.

How long does it take it to sort a list of 100?

Comment: It takes between 4390ms and 5038ms for 100 elements, 12740ms and 13608ms for 1000 elements in my computer.